# the remote server returned an error notfound

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I create get requests on the server in foreach

```
foreach (ulong id in IDList)
        GetData(Convert.ToInt32(id));
```

My request:

```
public void GetData(int id)
        {
            string url = String.Format(GET_URL, id);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "Get";
            request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadCallbackData), request);
        }
```

And My response where I get exception: "the remote server returned an error notfound"

```
      private void ReadCallbackData(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
            {
                try
                {   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                   }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {}     
}
```

When I tested on emulator I didn't get this exception, only on device and when I have many ID. When I have 5-10 ID I also didn't get this exception